# Datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

I have a data frame similar to the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Start_Date       |  End_Date         | Jan-16 | Feb-16 | Mar-16 | Apr-16 | May-16   |
| 2016-02-20 17:40 |  2019-11-20 16:31 |  0     | 1      | 1      | 1      | 1        |
| 2016-03-11 15:12 |  2020-11-01 12:12 |  0     | 0      | 1      | 1      | 1        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If the start and end date fall in between January 2016 to December 2020, I need to put a 1 or else a 0 using PANDAS in the respective month column. For example, in the first row, the date is Feb 20, 2020. Therefore, there is a 0 in the Jan-16 column and 1 in Feb-16, Mar-16, Apr-16 and so on.
Date is in Year, Month and Day format.

How do you achieve this?

Comment: `np.where((df['Start_Date'] > '01 Jan 2016') & (df['End_Date'] < '31 Dec 2020'), 1,0)` ?

Comment: no need to import `numpy` here; `df['in_range'] = ((df['Start_Date'] > '2016-01') & (df['End_Date'] <= '2020-12')).astype(int)` will do. just make sure the date columns are casted to datetime.

Comment: Thank you for your responses but this is not what I need. My apologies, I just updated the question for a clearer understanding. I need a 0 and 1 in each of the month columns. Is this question still something you can help me with?

Comment: so you have column for each month between January 2016 to December 2020, that is 60   columns for 5 years X 12 months ?

Comment: Yes, I have columns

Comment: So it sounds like you want to mark with 1 all the month columns that given date range spans, does not matter if it start before or ends after your main range.

Comment: What are you trying to do, is it for summing count of months? that would be way easier with out the columns step?

Comment: I need to take a sum of all the 1's in each column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219722/discussion-between-user13074756-and-tomasz-swider).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to count how many months occur between the start and end date,

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-02-20 17:40', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-11-20 16:31', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
num_months = (end_date.year - start_date.year) * 12 + (end_date.month - start_date.month)
```

num_months
print(num_months)